# Boolean to integer conversion

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have 3 separate Boolean variables, `bit1`, `bit2` & `bit3` and I need to calculate the decimal integer equivalent in JavaScript?

Comment: are you looking to convert each to a number or the combination into what amounts to a 3 bit set where i.e. bit3 would represent 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert boolean result into number/integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820683/convert-boolean-result-into-number-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820683/convert-boolean-result-into-number-integer

Answer (score 87):

```
+true //=> 1
+false //=> 0

+!true //=> 0
+!false //=> 1
```

Comment: I like concise answers but i'd appreciate if you could shortly explain it

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation for examples and explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()

Comment: @Doug Thanks to [@parsonsbots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358554/boolean-to-integer-conversion/19842255#comment99720871_19842255) half the way should be explained. Here's the rest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)

Comment: it is bad solution. try +undefined

Comment: @Jiraff537 - `undefined` is not a boolean value.

Answer (score 33):

Ternary operator is a quick one line solution:

```
var intVal = bit1 ? 1 : 0;
```

If you're unfamiliar with the ternary operator, it takes the form

```
<boolean> ? <result if true> : <result if false>
```

From Sime Vidas in the comments,

```
var intVal = +bit1;
```

works just as well and is faster.

Comment: Won't just `var intVal = bit1` do the trick? A boolean is after all either 1 or 0, so that assigns 1 or 0 automatically.

Comment: @Cupidvogel There is no such thing as a implicit conversion during assignment, and JavaScript has a separate boolean type (try `typeof true`, and refer to `Boolean`). So how would this do the trick?

Comment: Number conversion can be done with the `+` unary operator: `var intVal = +bit1;`. No need for the ternary here.

Comment: Dunno, just do something like `a = 5 > 44; alert(a+456.5);`, you will see `456.5`. Change 44 to 4, you will see `457.5`.

Comment: @Cupidvogel, the only issue is if you don't do any numeric operations on the boolean value, it won't be converted to a numeric type.

Comment: @Cupidvogel That's because the booleans are converted to 0/1 if you do arithmetic with them. That doesn't mean they're interchangeable in other contexts (e.g., output).

Comment: If I don't do numeric operations on it, then why would I need to seek its decimal value?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Thanks, I added your solution

Comment: @delnan, that is precisely the problem, I have been using var intVal = bit1 and it throws up random errors. what isthe format of the typeof true statement?

Comment: @Cupidvogel display in UI. If you concat bit1 with a string it will output "true" or "false". That's just one example

Comment: @user1661099 *What* errors? As for `typeof true` is just tells you the type of `true` is "boolean", which shows that booleans are separate from numbers.

Comment: Your second example should look like `<boolean> ? <result if true> : <result if false>`.  You have your operators reversed.

Comment: Ternary operator is perfect for me! I'm passing a `boolean` value to a function that writes the value to a database. But the DB is MySQL, so the `boolean` needs to be converted to a `tinyint`. Using your answer I can now do it as short and non-intrusive as possible like this (regular if-clause causes error): `writeToDb($("#checkbox").prop("checked")?1:0); //call to function`

Answer (score 20):

```
Number(true) // => 1
Number(false) // => 0
```

Answer (score 13):

If what you're asking is how to get the 3-bit integer value based on bit1 (MSB), bit2, and bit3 (LSB), you can just do the following:

```
var intval = bit1 << 2 | bit2 << 1 | bit3;
```

The left shifts (`<<`) will automatically convert the booleans to their corresponding int values.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DkYqQ/

Comment: finally a use for the shift `>>` operator ;)

Comment: Uh, I'd expect `bit3` to be shifted 2, `bit2` to be shifted 1 and `bit1` not to be shifted...

Comment: Lucero, I mentioned in my answer that I was assuming `bit1` to be the MSB.  It could go either way.

Answer (score 7):

Use ~~ :

```
bit1 = ~~bit1; // bit1 = true will return 1 or bit1 = false rtuen 0
bit2 = ~~bit2;
bit3 = ~~bit3;

sum = bit1 + bit2 + bit3;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function boolToInt(bool){ return bool ? 1 : 0 }
function boolToInt(bool){ return bool | 0 }
function boolToInt(bool){ return bool & 1 }
function boolToInt(bool){ return ~~bool }
function boolToInt(bool){ return +bool }
```

choose!

Comment: Can you explain what you did here?

Comment: **1.** analog: `if (bool == true) { return 1 } else { return 0 }`
**2,3,4.** automatically leads boolean to integer before bitwise operations
**2.** bitwise or:     `true | 0`  => 1;   `false  | 0`  => 0
**3.** bitwise and:  `true &1`  => 1;   `false & 1` => 0
**4.** bitwise not, double-inverted:
 `~true`  => -2;  `~ -2` => 1;
 `~false` => -1;  `~ -1` => 0;
**5.** analog `null + true`, `null + false`, where automatically leads boolean to integer and null to 0;

if to use function as is and bool === undefined  
functions 1-4 return 0;  
function  5 return NaN;

Comment: function boolToInt(bool){ return +bool } // what if **bool = undefined**

Comment: comment above - "...bool === undefined functions 1-4 return 0; function 5 return NaN"

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of using ternary operator, It will look something like this:

```
var i = result ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Also you can use, int myInt = (bit1)?1:0 ;

Comment: No, you can't use `int` in place of `var`, and while you can omit the whitespace, you shouldn't and it does not qualify as a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could be two things. Do you want the bitwise decimal equivalent, as if you'd squished bit1, bit2 and bit3 together in adjacent significant bits? Or do you want the hamming weight, where you count how many bits are set?

If you want the bitwise equivalent, basically you want to use a combination of bit-shifting and OR-summing, which is pretty common. In pseudocode:

```
var intResult = 0;
for each bit in {bit1, bit2, bit3}
{
   int bitVal = 0;
   if(bit) bitVal = 1;
   intResult = (intResult << 1) | bitVal;
}
```

If you want the hamming weight, then simply increment the result for each bit that is set:

```
var intResult = 0;
for each bit in {bit1, bit2, bit3}
   if(bit) intResult++;
```

If your language allows the use of booleans as integer values (true = 1, false = 0) these get easier:

```
//bit-concatenation
var intResult = 0;
for each bit in {bit1, bit2, bit3}
   intResult = (intResult << 1) | bit;

//hamming weight
var intResult = 0;
for each bit in {bit1, bit2, bit3}
   intResult += bit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function boolsToInt(){
  var s = "";
  for(var i in arguments)s+=arguments[i]?1:0;
  return parseInt(s,2);
}
```

input can represented as bool or int:

```
console.log(boolsToInt(true,false,true,true));
console.log(boolsToInt(1,0,1,1));
```