# Retrieve 1 is checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have this checkbox:

```
<input id="IsOutdoors" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

And I'm trying to retrieve `1` if it's checked.

I've tried:
`var IsOutdoors = $('#IsOutdoors').val();` Which always returns `1` no matter what.

I've tried: `var IsOutdoors = $("#IsOutdoors option:selected").val();` which returns nothing

I've tried: `var IsOutdoors = $('#IsOutdoors').is(':checked');` which returns true/false

Any other simple ways of returning the number? Thanks!

Comment: partially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820683/convert-boolean-result-into-integer-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var IsOutdoors = +$('#IsOutdoors').is(':checked')
```

Comment: This works great and is simple! Thanks to you and to everybody :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var IsOutdoors = $('#IsOutdoors').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
// ||
var IsOutdoors = document.getElementById('IsOutdoors').checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a ternary operator for that? What should `IsOutdoors` contain if the checkbox isn't checked?

```
var IsOutdoors = ($('#IsOutdoors').is(':checked')) ? $('#IsOutdoors').val() : false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the value of checkbox try:

```
var IsOutdoors = $('#IsOutdoors:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $checkbox = $('#IsOutdoors');

if( $checkbox.is(':checked')){
    alert($checkbox.attr('value'));
})
```