# Get value of checkbox as 1/0 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get values of all input fields with jQuery. I can do that with following code. However if the input field is checkbox, and it is checked, it will return "**on**". How can I get the value as **1** if checked?

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function() {

    inputs = $('.input');
    inputs.each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();  
        alert(value);
    }); 

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="input" />
<input type="text" class="input" />
<input type="checkbox" class="input">

<button>Get values<button>
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yDKdT/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to check if type of your element is equal `checkbox`:

```
if( $( this ).attr( 'type' ) === 'checkbox' ) {
    value = +$(this).is( ':checked' );
}
```

*Tip: `+` symbol will convert Boolean values into Integers: `1/0`*

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDKdT/2/)

Answer (score 4):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ESEYoJe/3/edit)**

```
var input = $('.input');

$('button').click(function() {

    input.each(function() {      
      var val = this.type=="checkbox" ? +this.checked : this.value ;      
      alert(  val  );
    }); 

});
```

What is does:

```
this.type=="checkbox" // Test if HTMLElement type is checkbox // (Boolean)
?
+this.checked // if true  // using '+', set boolean (true/false) to int (0/1)
:
this.value    // if false // just get the value
;
```

<sub>Additional reading: [Convert boolean result into number/integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820683/convert-boolean-result-into-integer-in-jquery)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use .is(':checked') instead of getting the value. 
This will return it as a boolean instead of getting "on" if checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .

```
$('button').click(function() {

    inputs = $('.input');
    inputs.each(function() {
        var value;
        if( $( this ).attr( 'type' ) === 'checkbox' ) {
            value = $(this).is( ':checked' ) ? 1: 0;
        }else
        {
            value = $(this).val();
        }
        alert(value);
    }); 

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUN8w/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 inputs.each(function () {
        if($(this).attr('type') == "checkbox") {
            value = $(this).prop('checked') == false ? 0: 1;
        }
        else {
        value = $(this).val();
        }
        alert(value);
    });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDKdT/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not mentioned any value for checkbox.Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input" value="1">
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/yDKdT/3/