# How exactly does PHP's spaceship operator compare strings, arrays and objects?

Tags: php, comparison, php-7, comparison-operators

I am wondering how the PHP spaceship operator compares strings, objects and arrays. For example, the below code.

```
echo "Its Me at SO" <=> "Its Me at SO";
```

will return 0, as I know all characters are same, count is same. But if I have a code like below:

```
echo "Its me at SO" <=> "its Me at so";
```

It will return 1, means that left side is greater than right side, but how? Is it comparing the ASCII values?

Now let's come to arrays. The below code will return 0, as both arrays are equal by count, values and values at each index.

```
echo [1,2,3] <=> [1,2,3];
```

But the below code returns -1

```
echo [1,2,3] <=> [3,2,1];
```

And I don't understand why. How this operator compares the arrays and how it calculates that the array on left is smaller than the array on right?

And the same goes for the objects.

Can anybody give a detailed answer that how it works with strings, arrays and objects?

Comment: It will do equality/inequality checks in the same way comparison operators do. So, it will compare strings same way it's with other operators and arrays or whatever. Spaceship is just a "wrapper" that still uses same logic underneath

Comment: "`echo "Its Me at SO" <=> "its Me at SO"; ` will return 0". Not for me it doesn't:it returns 1, which is what I'd expect it to, as "i" is greater than "I". Do you *really* get 0 for that?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error from my side. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Comparisons are performed according to PHP's usual type comparison rules (http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)".

1) Yes, it uses the ASCII values

2) If the arrays are different lengths, the Array with fewer values is smaller.

Otherwise it compares the arrays key by key, giving "earlier" values priority. For example comparing `$arr1[0]` to `$arr2[0]` first. If `$arr1` has a key that doesn't exist in `$arr2`, the arrays aren't comparable (eg if we're using non-numeric arrays).

```
// Arrays are compared like this with standard comparison operators
// $arr1 and $arr2 are arrays
function standard_array_compare($arr1, $arr2)
{
   // If either array has more values, that array is considered "larger"
    if (count($arr1) < count($arr2)) {
        return -1; // $arr1 < $arr2
    } elseif (count($arr1) > count($arr2)) {
        return 1; // $arr1 > $arr2
    }

    //Otherwise compare the array values directly
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr2)) {
            return null; // uncomparable, these arrays do not have the same keys
        } elseif ($val < $arr2[$key]) {
            return -1; // $arr1 < $arr2
        } elseif ($val > $arr2[$key]) {
            return 1; // $arr1 > $arr2
        }
    }
    return 0; // $arr1 == $arr2
}
```

Note, the above is not PHP's actual code, just an approximate representation of the logic used.

Essentially, then, it treats an array in a similar way to comparing a big-endian number. It compares `$arr1[0]` to `$arr2[0]`. If they are the different it returns -1 or 1 depending which is larger. If they are the same it moves on to `$arr1[1]` and `$arr2[1]`. If all values are the same it returns 0 (arrays are equal)

**While not exactly the same, it might be simpler to consider `[1,2,3] <=> [3,2,1]` as basically equivalent to `123 <=> 321...`**

Answer (score 2):

According to the new features [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

Comparisons are performed according to PHP's usual type comparison rules.

```
<?php
// Integers
echo 1 <=> 1; // 0
echo 1 <=> 2; // -1
echo 2 <=> 1; // 1

// Floats
echo 1.5 <=> 1.5; // 0
echo 1.5 <=> 2.5; // -1
echo 2.5 <=> 1.5; // 1

// Strings
echo "a" <=> "a"; // 0
echo "a" <=> "b"; // -1
echo "b" <=> "a"; // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaceship Arrays php8

```
 <?php
    echo [] <=> []; // result is  0
    echo [1, 2, 3] <=> [1, 2, 3]; // result is 0
    echo [1, 2, 3] <=> []; // 1
    echo [1, 2, 3] <=> [1, 2, 1]; // 1
    echo [1, 2, 3] <=> [1, 2, 4]; // -1
    echo [1,2,3,1] <=> [1,2,4];//1 //thats mean index first piority,1st array index number getter then 2nd array so its positive answer 1
    echo [1,2,4] <=> [1,2,3,1]//-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing arrays, objects or strings using the PHP spaceship operator (<=>) follows the *same* rules as with [other PHP comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

## String Comparison

Strings are compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order):

```
echo "a" <=> "a"; // 0
echo "a" <=> "b"; // -1
echo "b" <=> "a"; // 1

echo "a" <=> "aa"; // -1
echo "zz" <=> "aa"; // 1
```

## Array Comparison

Arrays are compared based on the following:

1. Array With Fewer Elements Is Considered Smaller;
2. Arrays With Same Length, But Different Keys Are Incomparable;
3. Arrays With Same Length and Keys Return First Non-Equal Result;
4. Arrays With Same Length and Key/Value Pairs Are Considered Equal.

```
// array with fewer elements is considered smaller

echo [1, 2] <=> [1, 2, 3]; // -1
echo [1, 2, 3] <=> [1, 2]; // 1
```

```
// arrays with same length but different keys are incomparable, always returning 1

echo ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3] <=> ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 4]; // 1
echo ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3] <=> ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 4]; // 1
```

```
// arrays with same length and keys return comparison result of first non-equal value

echo ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 4] <=> ['a' => 1, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 2]; // -1
```

```
// arrays with same length and key/value pairs are equal, regardless of order

echo ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3] <=> ['c' => 3, 'b' => 2, 'a' => 1]; // 0
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-are-arrays-compared-when-using-the-php-spaceship-operator) about this, which may be useful for those interested in learning more.

## Object Comparison

Object comparison is done based on the following:

1. Objects of Different Classes Are Incomparable;
2. Objects of Same Class With Different Property Values Return First Non-Equal Result;
3. Objects of Same Class With Same Property Values Are Equal.

```
// objects of different classes are incomparable, always returning 1

class Foo {}
class Bar {}

echo new Foo() <=> new Bar(); // 1
echo new Bar() <=> new Foo(); // 1
```

```
// objects of same class with different property values return first non-equal result

class Car
{
  public function __construct(
    private string $name,
  ) {}
}

$car1 = new Car('Porsche');
$car2 = new Car('Lamborghini');

echo $car1 <=> $car2; // 1
echo $car2 <=> $car1; // -1
```

```
// objects of same class with same property values are equal

class Car
{
  public function __construct(
    private string $name,
  ) {}
}

$car1 = new Car('Porsche');
$car2 = new Car('Porsche');

echo $car1 <=> $car2; // 0
echo $car2 <=> $car1; // 0
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-are-objects-compared-when-using-the-php-spaceship-operator) about this, which may be useful for those interested in learning more.

Comment: Please do not use Stack Overflow as a way of promoting your website/blog.  Your objective is too thinly veiled.  You are allowed to link to your blog in your profile if you wish.

Comment: @mickmackusa i already followed the rules as suggested by @Nick; my post is helpful and relevant to the topic and adds value.. i provided extensive information in the post and added link to my blog post as a reference .. which, I believe, is in accordance with the rules.. could you kindly tell me what seems to be your concern? i can improve it further.. thanks!

Comment: My concern is the frequency by which you promote your blog in your answers.  [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75569883/2943403) has FOUR links to your blog. Are you trying to help researchers or are you trying to boost your SEO rankings? It seems pretty clear to me that your primary goal is posting links to your blog and you are tiptoeing the edge of the rules about spamming Stack Overflow.

Comment: [this answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74353941/2943403) has EIGHT links to your blog.  See how this can be potentially perceived as self-serving?

Comment: i've 1100+ posts on my blog, and i've had it for 8+yrs.. plus i've contributed to stackoverflow for over 10yrs.. if my sole intention was to promote my blog, i would've done so for each and every post.. you can check my profile, i only do that seldom, and for topics that add something missing or valuable to the answers.. i will update the posts you mentioned, because it was posted a while ago, and i realized the issue just recently.. thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: updated all the ones you mentioned/commented on .. thanks for pointing it out 

Comment: Again, if you want to list your preferred blog links, perhaps use your profile.  If you want to make links in your blog to Stack Overflow -- feel free to spam your own blog pages with links to your SO answers.

Comment: it's a free resource like others on the internet, such as mdn, wiki, etc. if people can post links to my website and others on stackoverflow, why can't i post mine as a reference? i see where i had gone wrong, and i have since updated links  why are you starting an unnecessary feud with me?

Comment: This is not a feud.  ["_Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much._"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion#:~:text=Don%27t%20talk%20about%20your%20product%20/%20website%20/%20book%20/%20job%20too%20much.)  See also "_If the only reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic to your site, then please avoid posting answers._" at the bottom of that page.

Comment: i already removed the excessive links (which again, i admit, i wasn't aware of) .. i have since fixed those (and will fix others if i find any) .. and, for the record, i'm not selling anything here .. my genuine interest is to add value through the answers i add, which people are benefitting from .. from now on, if i post a link to my blog, i will do so in-line with community guidelines .. can we call it truce now? i need to sleep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256232/discussion-between-designcise-and-mickmackusa).